# Creating Azure SQL Database Server connection context New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I am trying to create an Azure SQL Database connection context e.g.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$ctx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName “mydatabasename” -credential $cred
```

or

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "[password1234]" -AsPlainText -Force;
$cred1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "databaseadmin", $pwd 
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName "myservername" -Credential $cred1
```

And the response is:

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:2 char:8
+ $ctx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName “myservername” - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.NewAzureSqlDatabaseServerContext
```

I've been through the docs and google searches but to no avail.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546736.aspx
http://sqlmag.com/powershell/manage-azure-sql-databases-powershell

Thanks
Pavel

Comment: What is the Microsoft Azure PowerShell version you're using?

Comment: Is this consistently reproducible at your end?

Comment: Yes, consistently reproduced.
Version           : 1.0.3
Name              : Azure
Author            : Microsoft Corporation
PowerShellVersion : 3.0

Comment: Interestingly it runs successfully in runbook.. Azure version 1.0.1. So obviously something to do either with v 1.0.3 and/or local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue in a PS runbook.  After doing some searching, I found a solution that worked for me.  Hopefully it will help you.

The error message isn't particularly helpful (big surprise), but the null object being referenced is the Azure subscription; I'm assuming the exception bubbles up from within the cmdlet rather than being thrown by your own code.  By adding these three lines to my code:

```
$cert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $automationCertificateName;
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName -Certificate $cert -SubscriptionId $subID;
Select-AzureSubscription -Current $subName;
```

I was able to get past the exception.  Above, `$automationCertificateName` is a variable asset that I added to the automation account.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/manage/azure-automation-automated-export for details about how to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I successfully created connection context:

```
$sqlServerUser = "test-user"
$sqlServerUserPassword = "P@$$w0rd"
$sqlServerName = "mysqlserver"

$sqlCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($sqlServerUser, ($sqlServerUserPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force))
$sqlContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $sqlServerName -Credential $sqlCred
```

Please see this for [more details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-sql-database-management-with-powershell/).